# simple php counter

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I'm working on wordpress query_posts. I want to show 12 posts on the index page,3 items in a row. So I want to have a "clear:both" css on the first item of each row. How can I do that please?

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 9, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
<div>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div> <!-- clear class on each 4th item -->
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Can't you put a width on the container these posts go into? Make it wide enough to fit 3 posts in, then when it gets to the 4th post there is no more room on that line so it will pop it underneath.

Comment: I see what you mean. But the items might not in the same height, also with margins, paddings stuff. It's always good to have more css classes for better control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 9, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
<div>
    <?php $i = 0; $attr = " class='clear_float'"; ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div<?php if(($i++)%3 == 0) {echo $attr;} ?>> <!-- clear class on each 4th item -->
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I added 2 lines.

`<?php $i = 0; $attr = " class='clear_float'"; ?>`

and

`<div<?php if(($i++)%3 == 0) {echo $attr;} ?>> <!-- clear class on each 4th item -->`

===== UPDATED =====

To add 3rd item class, I would suggest adding class to all items, for simplicity and even more control

To do so, before the loop:

```
$i = 0;
```

Inside the `div` in the loop:

```
<div class="item-<?php echo (($i++) % 3) + 1 ?>">
```

So that, for each line, the first item has class = `item-1`, the 3rd item has class = `item-3`

Comment: Can we add another class "last_item" to the 3rd item of each row please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    if (have_posts() ....): the_post(); ?
        $class = ((++$counter % 3) == 0) ? ' class="clearme"': '';
?>
    <div<?php echo $class ?>> <!-- clear.... -->
         ...
```

Initialize your counter to be zero. Increment it by one, divide by 3 and check if the remainder is 0 (implying it's an even multiple of 3), in which case you set your clearing class/style. In less terse code:

```
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    if ($counter > 3) {
        $counter = 0;
    }

    $remainder = (int)($counter / 3)
    if ($remainder == 1) {
         // will be 1 when $counter is 3
         $class = ' class="clearme"';
    } else {
         $class = '';
    }
```